# Query a SharePoint list with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list

I am a new SharePoint developer, and I am finding SharePoint to be a bit difficult. I have been looking for a way to query a SharePoint 2013 list with JavaScript for a while now, and I can't find an clear solutions.

What I am trying to do is to validate if an entered email address exists in my "subscription list". This will occur every time a certain button is clicked. The validation will happen in a modal view which I am yet still trying to create.

Some of the posts I have seen online talk about the `sp.js` file which I am not sure where I will find. Also, are the some good tutorials for SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Ever tried http://camelotjson.codeplex.com/?

Answer (score 2):

Include `SP.js`, `SP.Runtime.js` and `Microsoft.Ajax.js`. Your JavaScript could look like this (using jQuery for convenience ...):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://<DomainName>/<PathToWeb>/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<ListTitle>')/items",
  type: "GET",
  headers: {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
  },
  success: function(data){
      $.each(data.d.results, function (key, value) {
        $("#ParentContainerId").append($("<pre></pre>")
                              .html(value.Title);
      });
  },
  error: function(error){
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
});
```

n.b. If you need other fields than ID or Title, you must include them in a select statement at the end of the request URL using the InternalName as described [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111473/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-reliable-way-to-retrieve-all-field-values-of-a-list-it):

```
?$select=FileLeafRef
```

There are more [examples on how to retrieve and work with SharePoint ListItems using REST](http://blogs.technet.com/b/fromthefield/archive/2013/09/05/working-with-sharepoint-list-data-odata-rest-and-javascript.aspx) in the MS TechNet  and a good [documentation of the REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292552.aspx) in MSDN.

Comment: Please add more details to your answer, even if it is copy-pasted and quoted from that link. A short description would work also. As it is not it is a *link-only* answer and it is not admitted.

Answer (score 1):

There are two major ways to query SharePoint data using javascript:
1) [Javascript Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201%28v=office.15%29.aspx). In this case you will need to add SharePoint javascript libraries which are located on SharePoint server in layouts virtual folder. 
2) [REST services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I used [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) successfully for years (although I don't do Sharepoint currently and I have only worked with 2007/2010).

I believe you are looking for [GetListItems](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems&referringTitle=Lists) more specifically.